# Identify if a string is camelCase

Tags: php, validation, string-formatting, camelcasing, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to get PHP_CodeSniffer to check for camelCase in class names, however it seems to me camelCase checking is impossible (without a dictionary, including *techy* words).

I've raked the internet but so far the only options I've seen would be if the string had some common delimiter to explode from - i.e. underscore, space between words etc.

And even this is not useful as checking could only be accurate if the name *accurately/always* contained a delimiter between each word.
And the point of "checking" would be to determine if the name is not formatted correctly, and this could include not delimiting correctly.

Also, resources on PHP_CodeSniffer are either rare, or so basic and techy only the writer/developer would understand it.

### Current Standard Sniff Checks

I've found this code in some of the current Sniffs (i.e. Squiz and PEAR standards):

```
if (PHP_CodeSniffer::isCamelCaps($functionName, false, true, false) === false)
```

However, I've looked at the PHP_CodeSniffer core code and this function only does the following:

```
// Check the first character first.
// Check that the name only contains legal characters.
// Check that there are not two capital letters next to each other.
// The character is a number, so it cant be a capital.
```

These basic checks are better than nothing, although arguably useless for their supposed intended purpose, as they do not really check for camelCase at all.

### The Question

How can a Sniff (or i.e. PHP script) know which "words" to check in a given string to identify if the string is 100% camelCase?

---

### EDIT

### Examples

Correct camelCase: `class calculateAdminLoginCount`

```
// Not camelCase
class calculateadminlogincount

// Partially camelCase
class calculateadminLogincount
```

How can the `isCamelCaps()` function (or any PHP script for that matter)  catch the above two examples?

How can the function or a PHP script identify "separate words" from a string, when it has no concept of "words" without feeding it that info (i.e. from a dictionary)?

Even if a script where to explode, what would it explode based on?

Take `class calculateadminLogincount`
How can any PHP script identify that `calculate` `admin` `Login` `count` are different words in that string to then be able to check if: 1st letter 1st word is lowercase, then all subsequent words 1st letters are uppercase?

### `isCamelCaps()` function

```
public static function isCamelCaps(
    $string,
    $classFormat=false,
    $public=true,
    $strict=true
) {

        // Check the first character first.
        if ($classFormat === false) {
            $legalFirstChar = '';
            if ($public === false) {
                $legalFirstChar = '[_]';
            }

            if ($strict === false) {
                // Can either start with a lowercase letter, 
                // or multiple uppercase
                // in a row, representing an acronym.
                $legalFirstChar .= '([A-Z]{2,}|[a-z])';
            } else {
                $legalFirstChar .= '[a-z]';
            }
        } else {
            $legalFirstChar = '[A-Z]';
        }

        if (preg_match("/^$legalFirstChar/", $string) === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check that the name only contains legal characters.
        $legalChars = 'a-zA-Z0-9';
        if (preg_match("|[^$legalChars]|", substr($string, 1)) > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($strict === true) {
            // Check that there are not two capital letters 
            // next to each other.
            $length          = strlen($string);
            $lastCharWasCaps = $classFormat;

            for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $ascii = ord($string{$i});
                if ($ascii >= 48 && $ascii <= 57) {
                    // The character is a number, so it cant be a capital.
                    $isCaps = false;
                } else {
                    if (strtoupper($string{$i}) === $string{$i}) {
                        $isCaps = true;
                    } else {
                        $isCaps = false;
                    }
                }

                if ($isCaps === true && $lastCharWasCaps === true) {
                    return false;
                }

                $lastCharWasCaps = $isCaps;
            }
        }//end if

        return true;

    }//end isCamelCaps()
```

### EDIT 2

A little info for those wondering if this is worthwhile or not, or if I'm just "messing around" and "having fun":

It is imperative for class names to be correctly named throughout, as the file/folder structure and names and class names have to match in order for the autoloader to work solidly.

While I have checks in the Core code itself for checking and handling such issues if a script, class, etc cannot be loaded (of course), there's nothing wrong with additional scripting (PHP_CodeSniffer) to run through all files and tell me where a potential issue may lie.
Even if just for a second check, especially as it also ensures code base is tidy, correctly structured, and has continuity throughout.

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings that are causing problems, where something is identified as camelCase but isn't, or vice versa?

Comment: I don't understand how the `isCamelCaps` tests are inadequate. What example fails those tests?

Comment: Hmm, that's super tricky and probably impossible. The best I can think of is a "tolerance" limit to throw warnings if there is a possible fail (but not definite.) For example, if there are 20 characters and only one capital letter, that's a "possible failure."

Comment: @sjagr char count might be a useful idea. Won't be accurate, as can have long words, short words, etc, but coupled with the other checks it might be something I can play with. Whatever checks I end up with in total, they'll only be a warning/notice which can be ignored, or sometimes may end up being useful.

Comment: Exactly what I mean! Combine it with the dictionary thing too maybe. Generally if you're doing programming right, you're not going to have lengthy words in a camelCase variable or class name.

Comment: This seems like a giant waste of time for little improvement in code quality, but I can't stop thinking about it.  You could analyze each character, concatenate to previous, and check for dictionary presence.  But that won't get you spelling mistakes or shorthand  "calcAdminLoginCount"  or "clcAdminLoginCount".  You'd have to start at the very next letter after streaming the entire word and no match.  Perhaps a Lucene based DB could help find words?

Comment: Scan the word character by character, split apart based on capital letters.  Check the dictionary + jargon for each part.  If any fail, then you don't have proper camel case (or you need to add to your jargon file)

Comment: Why?  What is the goal?  Is this just a fun exercise in finding tricky strings?

Comment: What's with the negativity? Where does one draw the line with "doing things correctly"? It's not about "tiny little pointless tweaks in code quality" it's about ensuring hundreds or more files of code conform to some standard, and have continuity throughout. Many things on their own merit could be argued as pointless, but as a collection can make a better code base.

Comment: @greg_diesel "fun  exercise in finding tricky strings" - why jump to such a wild *conclusion*?

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the function names for correct capitalization by breaking apart the word where the case transitions.  For each part of the original function name, look up that sub-word in a dictionary or a dictionary + jargon file ('calc', 'url', 'admin', etc (perhaps check jargon first)).  If any sub-word fails then the proper capitalization is not in place.

You can use Solr or ElasticSearch to break your words apart for you with the WordDelimiterFilter in Lucene.  This will create sub-words when the case changes:

`"PowerShot" -> "Power" "Shot"
 "LoginURL" => "Login" "URL"`

You can either insert the words directly into these NoSQL databases and do your analysis later, or you can (at least in ES) simply use the word delimiter token filter to break apart your query without actually saving the results.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Example:

calcAdminLogin  =>  calc Admin Login

calcadminlogin   =>  calcadminlogin

If you have a supplemental dictionary that contains words like 'calc' and 'admin' then the first function name would decompose into 3 words that will be present in a dictionary, therefore the camel case is correct.

In the second example 'calcadminlogin' will fail to be found in the dictionary, therefore the camel casing is incorrect.

Comment: "*breaking apart the word where the case transitions*" But then you are relying on using the very thing which the script is checking for errors in. A camelCase checker is to find where some dev hasn't correctly used camelCase. If they have not correctly used camelCase, then there will be no *case transition* to break/split from, and so a checker using *case transition* would become useless. It would only work when the name is correctly camelCased. As I outlined in my question - it's seemingly impossible to split a string containing "words" without using a dictionary. Unless I've misunderstood?

Comment: " If they have not correctly used camelCase, then there will be no case transition to break/split from"  ... and therefore the dictionary look up will fail.

Comment: The dictionary won't fail due to incorrect case (could use case insensitive). The problem is more non-dictionary words, techy words etc. e.g. `calcUsrLoginCount`. Dictionary approach is a lot of work, adding some DB called within PHP_CodeSniffer etc, and as it won't be 100% accurate I don't see it worthwhile pursuing. Hence why I raised this question to ask prowling techies for other answers.

Comment: it has nothing to do with case insensitive or sensitive searching of the dictionary, please read the updated example.

Comment: "*In the second example 'calcadminlogin' will fail to be found in the dictionary*". No. Crude example: Loop the entire dictionary data;  `$dictWord = "Current_Loop_Dictionary_Word"` (let's say "admin" at the moment) `$string = "calcadminlogin"`.  and IF `$dictWord` is found in `$string` (a simple `strpos()` search), IS `$dictWord` at position 0, IF TRUE IS first letter lowercase, ELSE POSITION !== 0 IS first letter uppercase. A a dictionary would make this simple, but a lot of hours/work. And it *won't* be *100%* accurate given techy words, techy abbreviations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few scripts to try to "loosely" identify if a class name is camelCase.

Some of the scripts I wrote for my scenario won't help others, eg they're *too* specific to my own naming conventions (I've not included them here).
So my actual collection of scripts makes it all worthwhile, but hopefully the ones more generic below will help someone else.

For example I prefix class names with a lowercase word, so I check if the word after that prefix is uppercase.
For those (most people) who do not prefix class names with a specific word, then it's easy enough to check first char of string is lowercase.

Criticisms very welcome.

---

### Only allow mixed case alpha

This makes sure the class name only contains upper or lower case alpha letters (A-z), which is needed for the camelCase checks (if you remove this script, you'll need to change the other scripts to accommodate for the potential of non-alpha chars).

```
/** Check string is only alpha (A-z) */
if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
  $error = '%s name must only contain alpha chars (A-z)';
  $phpcsFile->addError($error, $stackPtr, 'AlphaChars', $errorData);
  return;
}
```

---

### No two uppercase chars together

Some standards allow for acronyms etc, however my standards do not allow this as it's not strict camelCase and breaks the flow of reading.

e.g. `userSitePHPLogin` is invalid, and `userSitePhpLogin` is valid.

(There's probs a more elegant way of doing this, but it works fine and given it's for PHP_CodeSniffer, I don't need micro optimisation)

```
/** Check for uppercase chars together */
$nameUppercaseExplode = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $name);
$totalIllegalUpperChars = 0;

foreach ($nameUppercaseExplode as $namePiece) {
  if (strlen($namePiece) == 1) {
    $totalIllegalUpperChars++;
  }
}

if ($totalIllegalUpperChars >0) {
  $warning = 'Class name seems invalid; 
  Total '.$totalIllegalUpperChars.' uppercase chars not part of camelCase';
  $phpcsFile->addWarning($warning, $stackPtr, 'UppercaseTogether', $errorData);
}
```

e.g. class name `DUserPHPUserclassLogin` returns:

> Class name seems invalid; Total 4 uppercase chars not part of camelCase

It's not perfect, as it's 1 out on that check.
But it will only return a warning if there is at least 1 occurrence of uppercase together.

e.g. class name `classDUserPhpUserLogin` returns:

> Class name seems invalid; Total 1 uppercase chars not part of camelCase

So this at least prompts the dev to check the name and fix it as appropriate.

---

### Check if total uppercase chars less than total words

Thanks to [sjagr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188035/sjagr) for the idea.

"Total words" is of course a "guessed" figure, based on 5 char average for each word - because it seems the official average is around 4.7 chars per average word.

```
/** Loose check if total (guessed) words not match total uppercase chars */
$totalWordsGuess = ceil(strlen($name) / 5);
$totalUpperChars = strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $name));

// Pointless if only 1 word (camelCase not exist)
if ($totalWordsGuess >1) {

  // Remove the first word which should be lowercase
  // (first word should be checked in separate check above this one)
  $totalWordsGuess--;

  if ($totalUpperChars < $totalWordsGuess) {
    $warning = 'Expected '.$totalWordsGuess.' camelCase words in class name; 
    Found '.$totalUpperChars;
    $phpcsFile->addWarning($warning, $stackPtr, 'BadCamelCase', $errorData);
  }

}
```

I've tested it and works quite well (it is only a warning for *potential* issues).

For example, using class name `UserLoginToomanywordsWithoutcamelCase`, PHP_CodeSniffer returns:

> Expected 7 camelCase words in class name; Found 5

If too many false positives are returned (different devs use different words etc), then tweak the current "5" up or down a notch.

**Edit**: Updated this above script:

- Added condition so script only runs if more than 1 word, as 1 word
  cannot be camelCase.
- Added code to deduct 1 from the total guessed words (`var --`), to
  account for the first word being lowercase and so no uppercase count
  will exist for it.

You should have a separate check above this one to check the first word, which `returns` if first word is not lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended regex for camelCase validation which allows single-letter words, but denies ALLCAPS acronyms: `^[a-z]+(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]?[a-z]+|\d+|$)|\d+)*$`

Breakdown: ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kf76If/1))

```
^                  #start of the string
[a-z]+             #one or more lowercase letters
(?:                #start non-capturing group1
   [A-Z]           #one uppercase letter
   (?:             #start non-capturing group2
     [A-Z]?[a-z]+  #an optional uppercase letter followed by one or more lowercase letters
     |             #OR
     \d+           #one or more digits
     |             #OR
     $             #end of string
   )               #end non-capturing group2
   |               #OR
   \d+             #one or more digits
)*                 #end non-capturing group1, repeat zero or more times
$                  #end of string
```

In layman's terms, a camelCase string:

- MUST start with at least one lowercase letter,
- MAY only contain lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and digits,
- MAY contain only lowercase letters if comprised of a lone word,
- MAY have single-letter "words" in uppercase,
- MUST NOT have acronyms expressed in uppercase,
- MUST NOT have lowercase letters after the first word unless prepended with an uppercase letter
- MAY have an uppercase letter if it is the start of a "word" or a single-letter word.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vmSIn))

```
$camelTests = [
    'hereIsOne',
    'andAnother',
    'tryAThirdOne',
    'kebab-case',
    'getUuid',
    'getUUID',
    'snake_case',
    'mysteryMethod1',
    'printIf0Or1',
    'itsAMeWario',
    'acronymOMGInMiddle',
    'DELIMITED_CONSTANT',
    'a1AndA2',
    'a1andA2',
    'StudlyCase',
    'FLOTUS',
    'makePlanC',
    '4Life',
    'wakeInTheAM',
    'code1B35F2',
    '42',
    'aB1c1De'
];

foreach ($camelTests as $test) {
    printf(
        "%s%s\n",
        str_pad($test, 20),
        preg_match('/^[a-z]+(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]?[a-z]+|\d+|$)|\d+)*$/', $test) ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL'
    );
}
```

Output:

```
hereIsOne           PASS
andAnother          PASS
tryAThirdOne        PASS
kebab-case          FAIL
getUuid             PASS
getUUID             FAIL
snake_case          FAIL
mysteryMethod1      PASS
printIf0Or1         PASS
itsAMeWario         PASS
acronymOMGInMiddle  FAIL
DELIMITED_CONSTANT  FAIL
a1AndA2             PASS
a1andA2             FAIL
StudlyCase          FAIL
FLOTUS              FAIL
makePlanC           PASS
4Life               FAIL
wakeInTheAM         FAIL
code1B35F2          PASS
42                  FAIL
aB1c1De             FAIL
```

---

If allowing acronyms to be all-caps in your style of camelCase, then the pattern is less complicated: `/^[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+)*$`

---

These patterns can be used to enforce consistent, valid camelCase naming conventions in your editor (e.g. PHPStorm)

[image]

p.s. If you want to know the other patterns in my projects...

- PHP StudlyCase / Class names: `(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]?[a-z]+|\d+|$)|(?!^)\d+)+`
- PHP Constants: `[A-Z]+(?:_(?:[A-Z]+|\d+))*`